# How would you add Active Admin index columns from a sibling table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

In my Customers_Rewards active admin I currently display columns from the Customer_Rewards and Customer data table, but I also want to display columns (such as store_id) from the Order data table.

```
ActiveAdmin.register CustomerReward do
    menu :parent=>"Customers", :priority=>10, :label=>"Activated Rewards"

  index do
    selectable_column
    column("Customer ID"){|u| u.customer.id }
    column("Store ID"){|u| u.order.store_id }  #DOES NOT WORK
    column("First name"){|u| u.customer.first_name }
    column("Last name"){|u| u.customer.last_name }
    column("Email"){|u| u.customer.email }
    column :reward
    column :points_redeemed
    column :expires_at
    column :redeemed_at
    bool_column :is_active
    actions
  end
 _____________________________________________________
class CustomerReward < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, :order => 'is_active desc, is_default desc'
  has_many :customer_rewards
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

---

```
I get an error message of: 
 undefined method `order' for #<Customer:0x007fb1dc2e3160>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`u.order.store_id` means you tell Rails to fetch `order` from association between `orders` table and `customer_rewards` table, but there is no such relation.

What you can do though, is to call

```
u.customer.orders
```

which will return all orders of the customer, who IS in relation with `CustomerReward` object (`u`).

I don't know based on what would you fetch concrete `store_id`, since

```
u.customer.orders
```

will return a collection, thus there will be a collection of `store_id`s - you can check it by calling

```
u.customer.orders.pluck(:store_id) # same as map(&:store_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! It currently works but it lists every store ID for each user: 


| CustomerID | Store ID | First name | Last name | Email | Reward  |

   82910           (2, 2, 10)     Amber            Rield      (a@b.com)   50
   82910           (2, 2, 10)     Amber            Rield      (a@b.com)   150
   82910              2, 2, 10     Amber            Rield     (a@b.com)   100



How would I get the specific store ID that is associated with the specific order instead of listing them all? Thanks again

Comment: @BrysonWatabu yea, it works as intended. As I've said, I don't know the conditions basing on which you would distinguish only one needed `store_id`  - but if you know it - go for it. Let me know if I can help you any further, and consider accepting the answer if it is helpful :)

Comment: Is it possible to go down the line of maybe 3 other tables by their ID's in order to get a specific store_id?  Does Active Admin only allow reference to what it belongs to and whatever it "has" (has_one/has_many)? Does active admin allow complex queries or just whatever is has associated to? How deep can an association get? Thanks!

Comment: @Bryson Watabu AA would allow you pretty much everything what is possible within Ruby/Rails - if you can do something with rails, it is possible in AA. So if you have a thought of how to reach the 3rd table `store_id` in Rails - no limitations by AA are there